# Is there a name, and symbol, for how quickly an object changes spacetime coordinates, in each direction?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames

If an object is changing spacetime coordinates, that are measured from some inertial reference frame A, at some rate in its own reference frame, is there a name and symbol for this spacetime vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [proper velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_velocity) for the spatial coordinates, and the [four-velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity) if you include time as well.